# Issue when open a installed web app from Mobile (add to home screen)

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, manifest, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

I have created a web app, PWA, and made it possible to add to Homescreen. When I add it to my mobile and try to open it, it doesn't open and Chrome stops working.

The same web app is working when launched from a desktop.

Here my manifest file:

```
   { 
    "gcm_sender_id": "********",
    "name": "*** **",
    "short_name": "***",
    "description":"**",
    "icons": [{
      "src": "icons/** 512x512.png",
        "sizes": "128x128",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/** 512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#032d31",
    "theme_color": "#032d31"
  }
```

Comment: How did you add the app to the mobile home screen? Using the pop up when you visit your website? Are you using Android or iOS?

Comment: followed this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners, I am using Android

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can have a look at an [article I wrote about it](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa), maybe you find a missing setting.

Another thing: "gcm_sender_id"is [obsolete and no more used](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) (maybe this triggers the error). 
You should use FCM now (Firebase Cloud Messaging) that implements the Web Push interface and does not need to put anything in the web manifest.

Comment: I have removed gcm_sender_id, keep doing the same thing.

Comment: I note, that when I remove start_url to "", my app launch really fine on mobile, but goes to manifest file. When I add something to start_url, like "/", my app doesn't open from mobile, and chrome stop's working

Comment: Where did you store the manifest file (root or subfolder)? The start_url represents the start URL of your web application. It is the URL that is loaded when the user launches the application from the home screen. Does the access to the manifest file requires credentials or can you access without any login?

Comment: I am hosting the app in Hostgator. The father folder is named (/home4/myusername) and then have subfolders, like ssl, temp, access-logs, public_HTML, and others. My entire site is on Public_HTML folder and my manifest.json too. I have tried to put manifest file in /home4/myusername but i don't now how to href the file when <link rel="manifest" href="?/manifest.json">

Comment: If the same app is working on desktop, then I guess the issue is with Android. On the desktop if you open Chrome Dev Tools and access the "Application" tab, can you see that the Manifest properties are listed correctly and the service worker is also active and running? This at least would confirm that the manifest settings are correct. You can try adding the attribute `crossorigin="use-credentials"` to the `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">`

Comment: yes, If I access the Dev Tools application's page, my manifest is fine.